# Input[type="image"] won't budge

Tags: css, input

I tried to make the button go down with margin, padding, top to be on the same level as other input and label, but it won't budge.

html code: see image[image]

```
   input[type="image"] .button-update-cart{
top:100px;
}
```

On the form, image is out of the place for example: see this image [image]

**EDIT**

```
.page-cart .cart-totals .promo-code .field .button-update-cart{
position:relative;
}

.page-cart .cart-totals .promo-code .field input[type="image"]
{
top:100px;

}
```

it doesnt work :(

Any insight will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the element `position: relative` to have the `top` have any effect.

Comment: @cwolves @Pekka I added position:relative to input .button-update-cart but still no effect? Or you mean I need to give div promo-code the position relative before top for input will take effect?

Comment: @Josephine no, I mean the `button-update-cart`. What browser are you trying this in?

Comment: @Pekka, I am trying both in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Josephine just add the `position: relative` to the same class you are doing the `top` on

Comment: @Pekka, ha it worked duh me i tested wrong website: live and dev. I tested dev one when I should test live one. Thank you so much for your help!